# Как исправить ошибку при закрытии выпадающего списка?

Tags: html, css

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
wrapper.addEventListener('click', function() { 
 var list = document.querySelector('.hidden_list');
   if (list.style.display == 'none') {
   list.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
   list.style.display = 'none';
   }
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #acacac;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.hidden_list {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 19px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Клик ми</p>
  <div class="hidden_list">
    <ul>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть выпадающий список, открывается хорошо, но он закрывается и тогда, когда нажимаешь на сам выпадающий список, видимо это происходит из-за того что родительский элемент растягивается на высоту выпадающего списка, а событие стоит на этот самый родительский блок. Что можно сделать что бы исправить такую ошибку?

Comment: Посмотри,что такое паттерн переключателя.По сути тебе просто переменная счетчик нужна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно остановить всплытие события по клику на список:

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
var list = document.querySelector('.hidden_list');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (list.style.display == 'none') {
    list.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    list.style.display = 'none';
  }
});

list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #acacac;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.hidden_list {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 19px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Клик ми</p>
  <div class="hidden_list">
    <ul>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
      <li>Элемент списка</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно повесить событие не на родителя, а на `<p>`:

```
var main_p = document.querySelector('.wrapper p');
main_p.addEventListener('click', function() {/*...*/})
```